# CakePHP 1.3 Loading a component at runtime

Tags: php, cakephp, components, cakephp-1.3, vendor

I'm required to load a component that contains a class that extends an object from a vendor.

As the vendor is loaded at runtime and the compenent is loaded at the initialisation of the controller, the script crashes.

How can I load this component at runtime and what class/filename convention should I use (CakePHP 1.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `App:import()` method to load at run time.

```
<?php
    App::import('Component', 'Mailer');
    // We need to load the class
    $Mailer = new MailerComponent();
?>
```

From the manual : http://book.cakephp.org/view/936/Importing-Controllers-Models-Components-Behaviors-#Loading-Components-939

Comment: I've tried this and I get error messages saying the class does not exists, it's maybe something to do with my file naming then? What should be the name and location of the file in your Mailer example? I really appreciate your fast response and help.

Comment: The component would be in the /app/controllers/components folder with a file name of mailer.php Docs : http://book.cakephp.org/view/902/File-and-Classname-Conventions

Comment: Your answers and references were really helpful and I ended up getting it working. Thank you.

Comment: The link in @JohnP's answer no longer works, try this instead: [importing-controllers-models-components-behaviors-views-and-helpers][1]


  [1]: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Configuration.html#importing-controllers-models-components-behaviors-views-and-helpers